# How to Calculate sum of digit from time given in excel sheet using PHP

Tags: php, math, time

here I having excel sheet contain two cell first cell format look like `[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM` now i want to calculate digit from time `12:00:08 AM` and formula is `=(HOUR(C351)*60)+(MINUTE(C351))+(SECOND(C351)/60)` in excel.

i'm using `PHP`  function to get hour,minute and second to calculate sum but getting `712` but actually ans was 0.133333333 as per excel sheet formula.

How to calculate this value using PHP?

Please help for this things.

Comment: Please show your PHP code. The main problem will be that the PHP calculates with 12:00:08 PM instead of 12:00:08 AM = 00:00:08. But the 712 is questionable nevertheless.

Comment: thank you for feedback, i have written following php code  <?php
$time = explode(":",'12:00:08');
$hour = $time[0];
$minute = $time[1];
$second = $time[2];

echo (($hour*60)) + ($minute) + ( $second / 60);
?>

Comment: Hello Axel, i got answer in excel hour() function return 0 to 23, so i have implemented code like this to calculate proper ans $timestamp = strtotime('11:0:10 PM');

$time = date('H', $timestamp);
 echo $time